# Desarrollando con la api de slack, con un servidor no accesible desde el puerto 80 desde afuera

Tags: slack-api

Estoy intentado desarrollar una api con slack api client, muy sencilla con dos botones que al cliquear uno de ellos obtenga datos de quien lo ha pulsado y responder.
Pero el primer problema que me encuentro es que mi servidor se encuentra en una red local que no es accesible desde la afuera, por lo tanto salck no puede acceder a un endpoint en este servidor.
La pregunta es si puedo realizar lo mismo que hace esta api pero con algún método que desconozca por ejmplo con RTMClient que creo que no es posible.

Gracias! .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese problema la vas a tener tanto con el [WebClient](https://api.slack.com/web) como con el [RTM](https://api.slack.com/rtm). Tu servidor (en este caso tu computadora de desarrollo) no es accesible para internet a menos que realices una [redirección de puertos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirecci%C3%B3n_de_puertos) (igual esto depende de tu ISP, aunque la redirección de puertos es lo más común para ISPs domésticos).

Para solucionar este tema podés utilizar [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) que te provee temporalmente de una url que realiza un [tunel](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%BAnel_(inform%C3%A1tica)) a tu computadora, de manera que resulta accesible desde internet. Slack también tiene una [guía](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/tunneling-with-ngrok) de cómo realizar el tunel con ngrok.

Comment: Hola, esto es un comentario?